# How to get average, highest and lowest values of input values

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Write a python program which can store the name of the student and their exam score. The program should be able to:

1. Calculate the average score for the students and print the average scores once you finish entering the student names and scores.
2. Summarize who get the highest and lowest.

I got stuck at how to find average and highest and lowest, this is my code :

```
students = {}

polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    name = input("enter your name: ")
    score = int(input("enter your score: "))
    
    students[name] = score
    
    repeat = input("would you like to add another student?" "(yes/no)")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False
        
print ("-------RESULT-------")
for name, score in students.items():
    print(name, "your score is: ", score )
    
total_sum = float(sum(score)) 
print (total_sum)
```

Comment: Hi in simple language, you can post your programming problem here. it is not good idea to ask whole solution.

Comment: Please don't expect people to do all your work for you. That is not what stackexchange is for. Show us what you have tried and what problems are you facing. There, people would help.

Comment: ohh sorry about that, i forgot to mention my work, i already edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Continue your code with the following, to get the average and max-min:

```
total_sum = sum(list(students.values()))/len(students)
highest=max(students, key=lambda x:students[x])
lowest=min(students, key=lambda x:students[x])

print('Average: ', total_sum)
print('Highest score: ', highest, '   ',students[highest])
print('Lowest score: ', lowest, '   ',students[lowest])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students = {}

def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

while True:
    name = input("enter your name: ")
    score = int(input("enter your score: "))

    students[name] = score

    repeat = input("would you like to add another student?" "(yes/no)")
    if repeat == 'no':
        break
    
print ("-------RESULT-------")
for name, score in students.items():
    print(name, "your score is: ", score )




avg = Average(students.values())

highest = max(students,key=students.get)

lowest = min(students,key=students.get)

print ('avg :',avg)
print ('highest :',highest)
print ('lowest :',lowest)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to this problem. I will describe elaborately.

```
import sys
students = {}

polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    name = input("enter your name: ")
    score = int(input("enter your score: "))
    
    students[name] = score
    
    repeat = input("would you like to add another student?" "(yes/no)")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False
        
print ("-------RESULT-------")
#We will use totalScore for keeping all students score summation.
#Initaly total score is 0.
totalScore = 0
#For getting lowest score student name, we need lowest score first. 
#Initaly we don't know the lowest score. So we are assuming lowest score is maximum Int value
lowestScore = sys.maxsize 
#We also need to store student name. We can use lowestScoreStudentName variable for storing student name with lowest score
#Initaly we don't know the student name. So we initialize it as an empty student list.
lowestScoreStudentName = []
#For getting maximum score student name, we need maximum score first. 
#Initaly we don't know the maximum score. So we are assuming lowest score is minimum Int value
maximumScore = -sys.maxsize - 1
#We also need to store student name. We can use maximumScoreStudentName variable for storing student name with maximum score
#Initaly we don't know the student name. So we initialize it as an empty student list.
maximumScoreStudentName = []

for name, score in students.items():
    totalScore = totalScore + score
    print(name, "your score is: ", score )
    if lowestScore > score:
        lowestScore = score
        #Making student list empty, since score is lower than before
        lowestScoreStudentName = []
        lowestScoreStudentName.append(name)
    elif lowestScore == score:
        #keeping all students in the list who gets lowest score
        lowestScoreStudentName.append(name)
        
    if maximumScore < score:
        maximumScore = score
        #Making student list empty, since score is higher than before
        maximumScoreStudentName = []
        maximumScoreStudentName.append(name)
    elif maximumScore == score:
        #keeping all students in the list who gets highest score
        maximumScoreStudentName.append(name)
    
total_sum = sum(list(students.values()))
average_sum = totalScore/len(students) 

print("Average score : " + str(average_sum))
print("Lowest Score holder students name: " + str(lowestScoreStudentName))
print("Highest score holder students name: " + str(maximumScoreStudentName))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess this may be helpful

```
student = []
student_1=[]
score = []
copy = [] 
loop = True
yes = ["YES","yes","y","Y"]
while loop:
    Name = input("Name : ")
    Score = int(input("Score : "))
    student.append(Name)
    score.append(Score)
    copy.append(Score)
    Enter_more = input("Write YES or Y or y or yes to add more names: ")
    if Enter_more in yes:
        continue
    else:
        break
score.sort()
score.reverse()
sum = 0
for i in range(len(score)):
    index = score[i]
    student_1.append(student[copy.index(index)])
    sum+=score[i]
    score[i] = student[i]
print("Average Score is "+str(float(sum/len(score))))
print("Highest Score is Scored by  "+str(student_1[0]))
print("Lowest Score is Scored by "+str(student_1[len(student_1)-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set your while loop as True to save the trouble of making another variable:

```
while True:
```

and break it with

```
    name=input("Enter your name: ")
    if name=='no':
        break
```

and to find your average you could do

```
average=(sum(students.values()))/len(students)
```

then finally for highest and lowest you can use the in built max and min functions as so

```
highest=max(students.values())
lowest=min(students.values())
```